# Convert Series to Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We need to convert three different series to a `dataframe` in Python 3.

Series 1 (Mean):

```
e1     40.355
e2     59.556
ec1    17.668
ec2    75.230
```

Series 2 (SD):

```
e1     19.815
e2     17.550
ec1    14.704
ec2    54.485
```

Series 3 (Max):

```
e1     87.36
e2     80.39
ec1    200.3
ec2    207.5
```

Above needs to be merged into a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Features     Mean       Standard Deviation     Max

e1           40.355     19.815                 87.36
e2           59.556     17.550                 80.39
ec1          17.668     14.704                 200.3
ec2          75.230     54.485                 207.5
```

What we have done so far is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    Mean = df.mean().round(3)
    SD = df.std().round(3)
    Max = df.max()

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Features', 'Mean', 'Standard Deviation', 'Max'])

    df2['Mean'] = Mean
    df2['Standard Deviation'] = SD
    df2['Max'] = Max

    print(df2)
```

Above prints/outputs the following:

```
        Features    Mean  Standard Deviation      Max
e1           NaN  40.355              19.815    87.36
e2           NaN  59.556              17.550    80.39
ec1          NaN  17.668              14.704    200.3
ec2          NaN  75.230              54.485    207.5
```

How can we set the index to features column such that the dataframe looks like the following:

```
        Features    Mean  Standard Deviation      Max
            e1    40.355              19.815    87.36
            e2    59.556              17.550    80.39
           ec1    17.668              14.704    200.3
           ec2    75.230              54.485    207.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat`, `rename_axis` and `reset_index`:

```
df2 = (pd.concat([Mean, SD, Max], 
                 keys=["Mean", "SD", "Max"], 
                 axis=1)
       .rename_axis(index="Features")
       .reset_index())

>>> df2
  Features    Mean      SD     Max
0       e1  40.355  19.815   87.36
1       e2  59.556  17.550   80.39
2      ec1  17.668  14.704  200.30
3      ec2  75.230  54.485  207.50
```